# how to populate dropdown menu with sorted array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array and i want to sorted it. However; I have an empty dropdown menu and i want to populated. Im stuck. How can populate my dropdown menu with the sorted array.

```
enter code here
<select id="dropdownList">
<option></option>
</select>

enter code here

var array = ["vintage","frames","treats","engraved", "stickers", "jewelerybox", "flask"];

array.sort(function(val1 , val2){
  return val1.localeCompare(val2);
});

console.log(array); // ["engraved", "flask", "frames", "jewelerybox", "stickers", "treats",
```

Comment: Why not just sort it by hand and write the option HTML? Judging by your code the array is always the same.

Comment: You need to either add elements to the DOM or set the `innerHTML` property to a string of `<option>` tags based on your sorted list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `for loop`,by writing it to `innerHTML` of the `select`

```js
var array = ["vintage", "frames", "treats", "engraved", "stickers", "jewelerybox", "flask"];

array.sort(function(val1, val2) {
  return val1.localeCompare(val2);
});

var select = document.getElementById("dropdownList");

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  select.innerHTML += '<option>' + array[i] + '</option>';

}
```

```html
<select id="dropdownList">

</select>
```